# preventing user from clicking on button more than once; blocked my controller action from executing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I added this jquery function to my form.

```
$('#NewVarianceSubmitButton').click(function () {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled")
});
```

Now, when I click on it the button is disabled but it does not submit the data to the database. If I remove the code above everything submits to the database just fine. Do I need to tell jquery to execute the controller action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch up your process:

```
$('#yourform').submit(function () {
    //run validation, if successful and all is going well...
    $('#NewVarianceSubmitButton').prop('disabled', true)
});
```

Comment: how to do this without using jQuery?